# solrCloud loadbalance using django and haystack

Tags: python, django, solr, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Are you aware of any python client that uses something similar to CloudSolrServer? I have a Django app that, for the time being, communicates with a single solr instance through Haystack. I am considering to move to SolrCloud, but I am wondering what load balancing options I have. Setting up a separate load balancer (somewhat zookeper-aware) in the middle is one solution.

Do you think that migrating to elasticsearch (elasticsearch-py which is used by haystack does a (simple) round-robin load balancing) is a better solution?